# Ruby String to Integer

Tags: массивы, строки, ruby

Есть строчка

```
variable = "{what's going on?:;##754658$}"

puts variable
#=> {what's going on?:;##754658$}

puts variable.class
#=> String
```

Нужно убрать из неё лишнее, чтоб получилось примерно так:

```
puts variable
#=> 754658

puts variable.class
#=> Integer
```

Как это сделать? У меня пока единственная мысль - преобразовывать в массив, удалять из него всё лишнее а потом обратно уже в число.
Но я не поверю что на руби нельзя сделать проще

Comment: решено. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов: удалить все не числа, а полученную в результате строку преобразовать к числу

```
>> variable = "{what's going on?:;##754658$}"
=> "{what's going on?:;##754658$}"
>> variable.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i
=> 754658
```

Comment: [Микрооптимизация: `variable.tr("^0-9", "")`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-tr)